# Search for a word before white-space

Tags: linux, grep, search, sed

I've got a file with some e-mails:

```
info@example.com info51351@hotmail.com
test@hello.com test6261@gmail.com
example@example.com example64262@gmail.com
```

And now... I need to find a way to search for specific e-mails address from the list on the left hand-side (before white-space), I already tried to grep/sed it but normally when I'm searching for word "info", I'm getting both results info@example.com and info51351@hotmail.com...

How I can tell linux to check only string before white-space?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Take the following dataset:

```
# cat mailaddresses.txt
info@example.com info51351@hotmail.com
test@hello.com test6261@gmail.com
example@example.com example64262@gmail.com
infotest@example2.com yadayada@example.com
superinfo@example.com yada@example.com
```

Using awk to get the first column:

```
# awk '{print $1;}' mailaddresses.txt
info@example.com
test@hello.com
example@example.com
infotest@example2.com
superinfo@example.com
```

And to get all the info@ you could just pipe the output to grep:

```
# awk '{print $1;}' mailaddresses.txt | grep '^info@'
info@example.com
```

And if you want all emails containing info before the @:

```
# awk '{print $1;}' mailaddresses.txt | egrep '^.*info.*@'
info@example.com
infotest@example2.com
superinfo@example.com
```

Comment: You don't even need to use `grep`, `awk` can also perform pattern/string matching natively: `awk '$1 ~ /^info@/ {print $1;}' mailaddresses.txt`

Answer (score 0):

For example

`grep ' info@' file` for matching the one on the second column.

`egrep '^info@' file` for matching the one on the first column.

Just put the match string between quotes so that bash executes grep with the whole string as a parameter rather than parsing them as different parameters.

Comment: Can I display the first value (from the left hand-side) without the an e-mail from the right hand-side?

Comment: Learn how to use awk for that.

Answer (score 0):

grep 'info@.* ' file 
should do the trick
alternatively, and ugly, awk '{print $1}' file | grep 'info@'

J.